# Npm вместо bower. Как разделить библиотеки кода и пакеты для сборки (напр. компиляции CSS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, npm, bower

Собираемся перейти на nmp вместо bower (в качестве менеджера зависимостей).

В bower все установленные библиотеки складывались в bower_component или др. отдельную папку.

Npm по умолчанию сваливаем все в node_modules смешивая библиотеки кода, gulp, компиляторы препроцессоров и т.п.

Есть возможность как-то отделить их?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать --prefix
чтобы разделить скачиванные папки

mkdir -p ./install/here/node_modules

npm install --prefix ./install/here